# On Diophantine approximation and irrationality proofs

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, irrational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

This question is an offshoot from this [previous MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342776).

I have a ratio of two numbers $a$ and $b$ (presumably both positive integers), where $a$ and $b$ are determined by some arithmetic / number-theoretic equation $f(a,b)=0$.

Let $S$ be the set
$$S = \{(a,b)|f(a,b)=0 \}.$$

Suppose that I have bounds for the sum
$$L(a,b) \leq \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a} \leq U(a,b).$$

If I want to prove that $S$ is empty, one way is to prove that the ratio $a/b$ (or equivalently, $b/a$) is actually irrational.

Since we know that, in general
$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a} \rightarrow \infty,$$
does the upper bound $U(a,b)$ guarantee an irrationality proof?

If anybody can point out to me a proof (in Diophantine approximation) that proceeds along similar lines, I will most certainly appreciate it.

Comment: You ask whether $\lim (a/b + b/a) = \infty$ ensures irrationality. I think the answer is no. Only $\liminf (a/b + b/a) = \infty$ ensures irrationality.

Comment: @NimaBavari, can you give specific examples for both of your claims that

$\lim(a/b + b/a) = \infty \not{\Rightarrow}$ irrationality,

and

$\lim \inf(a/b + b/a) = \infty \implies$ irrationality,

in an actual answer, so that I may be able to review and accept it, if needs be?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! I don't know if I can rigorously prove my claim but it's very intuitive. If I recall right, it is a standard procedure when working with Shnirelmann density: not only one element of a set but all of them should fall between a specific interval so that a certain property be satisfied. I can comment like this but I'm not sure if I can formally and elaborately convey my idea.